# Should I use definite article here?

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-article

It is argued whether it is better for students to travel abroad for a year before going to university.  This essay completely agrees on this idea for (**the** \ **no article**) benefits it brings to the youth.

I think "benefits" is specific because it means "the benefits of traveling abroad for students".  However, I am still talking generally about these benefits as I did not mention any specific benefits.  How to judge this?

Comment: I think it is specific enough to use "the". Though I would prefer "This essay completely agrees *with* this idea *because of* the benefits it brings to the *students*. "youth" isn't specifically referred to elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, include the definite article.  It sounds very awkward without it. You will delineate these benefits in your essay, so in this context the benefits are quite concrete and specific.

There are a few other little English issues, like the use of "better" without an explicit alternative and the use of "university" when Americans, at least, would say "college." Of course, Americans seldom take a year to travel before college, so you may not be writing for an American audience.

Here's how I would write it, for your reference:

> The question of whether students should take a year to travel abroad before college has been a subject of much debate.  In this essay, I support this practice by illustrating the many benefits it brings to those who participate in it.